# Angular Material Date picker issue inside kendo column filter

Tags: angular, kendo-ui, angular-material, datepicker, kendo-grid

I have a template for a kendo grid column filter where I use a material datepicker to select a date.

The issue that is happening when the kendo grid is located inside a material Dialog.

[Issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E44Yf.png)

As you can see on the image, the mat datepicker is appearing behind the filter. That happens because the mat-datepicker dialog is being instantiate in the cdk-overlay, in the same div that contains the grid, so they share the same Z-index.

[Inspector code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hjdUQ.png)

And the kendo-grid filter is being instantiated inside the app.component.

[Inspector code 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IVk1y.png)

I think that we have two possible solutions: instantiate the filter's kendo-popup inside the cdk-overlay div or move the mat-datePicker next to the kendo-popup with a higher z-index.

If I use a kendo-datepicker this issue doesn't happens because it is instantiate next to the kendo-popup but I need the mat-datepicker for designs requirements.

[Inspector code 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yPxL6.png)

Thanks in advance,

V

Answer (score 0):

My question was answered in telerik forum. I had to attach the following code to the @Component of my grid. With this modification, the kendo-popup is instantiated in the cdk overlay when I use my grid in a popup.

```
providers: [
    {
      // Provide the current component element as Popup container.
      provide: POPUP_CONTAINER,
      useExisting: ElementRef,
    },
    // Create a new Popup Service that uses the provided container.
    PopupService,
  ],
```